# QGis Making Column Value of Attribute table unique

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

For a shapefile, I have a field named *id* with the following contents in it:

```
1
1
2
2
```

I want to make these values unique such as:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Quantum GIS (using any plugin or other means) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Field Calculator in the Attribute table to assign the features unique values by checking "Update existing field", selecting the appropriate field, and entering `$rownum` in the Expression box. This will assign each feature its row number as its ID.