# Automate points data attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a list of points and I want to insert attribute number for each point. The number should increase from 1 to the last point. (30 in the example below)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [QGis Making Column Value of Attribute table unique](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49370/qgis-making-column-value-of-attribute-table-unique)

Comment: @Joseph the rownum are mixed. I have couple of listings like above and I need to start from 1 everytime.

Comment: What do you mean by "list"? If each set of points is a separate layer, the linked solution will still work fine.

Answer (score 4):

If your points were not plotted sequentially, and you still need to label it from west to east (left to right), please give a try to MMQGIS `sort` function:

(1) Create a new field "x_loc" with an expression `$x`

(2) Activate MMQGIS plugin `Menu | MMQGIS | Modify | Sort`

(3) On `Sort Attributes` dialog windo, give your point layer (e.g. points) to sort (ascending) by "x_loc" field  and save it to disk (e.g. C:/temp/sorted.shp).

[image]

(4) Open attribute table of this sorted layer and add new field "rownum" (expression $rownum) as a solution linked in Joseph's comment.

(5) Then the attribute may look like above RHS image. Annotate the points by "rownum" field. (black: original "id", red: "rownum")

[image]